# How to get \counterwithout in Latex to work?

Tags: latex, figure

I am trying to have my figures numbered with 1, 2, 3 and so on. But LaTeX is only numerating them with the section numbers (e.g 1.1 , 1.2 and so on) even though I used `\counterwithout{figure}{section}`. There is no error message. What could be the issue?

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{section}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\input{chapter/01_introduction}
%the figure is in a subsection as part of the introduction

\end{document}
```

This is what the `01_introduction` file looks like:

```
% !TEX root = ../root.tex
\section{Introduction}
\subsectiction{Title of the subsection}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{chapter/figures/fig_bsp.png}
\captionof{figure}{caption of the figure}
\label{fig:1}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) instead of code fragments

Comment: If I puzzle together the fragments to a compilable document and correct some typos, I do get `Figure 1`

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but you should really not use a `center` environment inside the figure, this will just add additional spacing. Better use `\centering`. Also it is not necessary to use `\captionof`, a simple `\caption` will do because this is already inside a figure

Comment: While making the minimal working example I figured out my mistake: I used a template which contained: `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}` which prevented my numeration from beeing 1, 2, 3.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @SandraHeckmann Glad you found the answer! You should post your solution as an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While making the minimal working example I figured out my mistake: I used a template which contained: '\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}' which prevented my numeration from beeing 1, 2, 3. Thank you for your help!